# What is the dimension of the vector space of functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

What is the dimension of the vector space of functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$?

I want to say that it is at least $2^{\aleph_0}$, but I have no idea how to sharply pin it down otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:** The cardinality of $\Bbb{R^R}$ (*all* the functions from $\Bbb R$ to itself, not just the continuous ones or whatnot) is $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$. And note that if $V$ is a vector space over an infinite field, with basis $B$, then $|V|=\max\{|B|,|F|\}$.

Comment: Wow ok $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ it is then.  Pretty monstrous (to a non-set-theory aficionado at least).  That's a very nice last equation you wrote.  Does it have a special name?  Where in standard books would I find such wonderful gems?

Comment: I don't know where you can find the last equation. It's not hard to prove if you know basic cardinal arithmetic. I don't know if it has a name either. I wrote a proof in an answer before, I'll go find it.

Comment: There we go: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/194287/622

Comment: Wonderful!  Thanks Asaf.