# What is the cardinality of the set of subgroups of $(\mathbb R, +)$?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, cardinals

Let $X$ be the set of subgroups of $(\mathbb R, +)$. What is $|X|$?

An attempt at a proof that $|X| = 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$:

Clearly $|X| \le 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$, because $X \subset P(\mathbb R)$. For a lower bound, let $H$ be a Hamel basis of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$. Since $H$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$ (and thus also over $\mathbb Z$), every subset of $H$ generates a distinct subgroup of $\mathbb R$. Since $|H| = 2^{\aleph_0}$ (I think), the set of all such groups then has cardinality $2^{|H|} = 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$. Since this is a subset of $X$, we must have $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}\le |X|$. Thus, $|X| = 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.

Does this work? Also, is there a way to prove this that isn't quite so reliant on Choice (needed for the Hamel basis of $\mathbb R$ and possibly some of the cardinality comparisons)?

Comment: Your claim that $|H| = 2^{\aleph_0}$ is correct, assuming choice; as proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/194287/822) by Asaf Karagila, a vector space $V$ over a field $F$ with a basis $H$ satisfies $|V| = \max(|F|, |H|)$.  Since $F= \mathbb{Q}$ is countable and $V = \mathbb{R}$ is not, we must have $|H| = |\mathbb{R}|$.

Comment: Proposition B of my JLMS paper with Guyot and Pitsch https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.1549 says (in ZFC) that for any uncountable abelian group $A$ of cardinal $\alpha$, the space $S(A)$ of subgroups of $A$ (with the compact topology induced by inclusion in $2^A$) has a subset homeomorphic to $2^\alpha$ (and in particular has cardinal $2^\alpha$). The proof in general is essentially the same as the one in the case of $\mathbf{R}$; in this latter case, as mentioned by Asaf, one can make the construction explicit enough to work in ZF (what's abusively called "without choice").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that there is a set of size $2^{\aleph_0}$ of real numbers which is linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$, even without the axiom of choice.

Then do the same proof as you did, as it's fine.

---

For the first part, [Is there any uncountably infinite set that does not generate the reals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696284/is-there-any-uncountably-infinite-set-that-does-not-generate-the-reals) is of interest towards a positive answer.

Comment: Ah, very nice. It seemed possible without choice, but I couldn't come up with such a set so I went with the Hamel basis. I'm kind of surprised there's such a simple way to define one.

Comment: How does one construct a linearly independent set of size $2^{\aleph_0}$ without choice?

Comment: @Nate: Follow the links!

Answer (score 0):

You can (**not**) modify your proof slightly to get rid of any (obvious) use of choice.

Define an equivalence relation on $\mathbb R$ by $x \sim y \iff x-y \in \mathbb Q$. This partitions $\mathbb R$ into equivalence classes of the form $[x] = x + \mathbb Q = \{x+q: q \in \mathbb Q\}$. It's easy to see each $[x]$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb R$.

Since $\mathbb  Q$ is countable so is each equivalence class. Write $(\mathbb R/\sim)$ for the collection of equivalence classes. 
Observe $\bigcup (\mathbb R/\sim)$ is a disjoint union of countable sets. So the union has cardinality $|\mathbb N| \times |(\mathbb R/\sim)| = |(\mathbb R/\sim)|$. But since the union is just $\mathbb R$ we get $|(\mathbb R/\sim)| = |\mathbb R|$ as required.

Comment: If each $[x]$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb R$, how come $0$ is only a member of $[x]$ when $x\in\Bbb Q$?

Comment: Oh, and also the last line uses choice in an essential way. It is consistent that $\Bbb{|R/Q|>|R|}$.

Comment: UGH you're right! Quick someone put up a better answer!

Comment: Actually, your edit is *also* wrong! :-)

Comment: I don't remember making that last edit. . . .

Comment: I sorry i edit my answer and modify your answer

Comment: Daron, in either case, I meant the edit you've made. In fact the argument can be repaired to exclude choice.